# How to keep Windows Phone app running in foreground

Tags: windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm building an app for Windows Phone 8, and the nature of the app requires that it keeps running in the foreground with no user interaction (similar to turn-by-turn navigation apps).  While I can find plenty of information on how to keep an app running in the background (for location tracking, etc), I can't find anything specifying how to keep the app running in the foreground without locking.

Does anyone know how this is done?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you looking for [IdleDetection on Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff941090%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)?

Short answer is, you'll need to change the [PhoneApplicationService.UserIdleDetectionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.shell.phoneapplicationservice.useridledetectionmode%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) property to Disabled. (Note that you're after UserIdleDetection not ApplicationIdleDetection).

Comment: I actually found that stuff about 5 minutes after I posted (of course!), but hadn't had the chance to test it on a device.  Thanks for the confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Changing IdleDetection is one way, but your application will likely be deactivated and in some cases tombstoned... but there is a better way to increase the chances for your application to keep running, specially if you are doing location tracking take a look to [Running location-tracking apps in the background for Windows Phone 8](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681691%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)